# find matching text and replace next line in yml

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I'm trying to find a line in a yml configuration file and replace the next line with a specific value. I tried sed, but it seems it is not replacing or not able to find the pattern. Below is the snippit of that yml file

```
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 14080
      bindHost: 15.213.48.154
      headerCacheSize: 512 bytes
      outputBufferSize: 32KiB
      maxRequestHeaderSize: 8KiB
      maxResponseHeaderSize: 8KiB
      inputBufferSize: 8KiB
      idleTimeout: 30 seconds
      minBufferPoolSize: 64 bytes
      bufferPoolIncrement: 1KiB
      maxBufferPoolSize: 64KiB
      acceptorThreads: 1
      selectorThreads: 2
      acceptQueueSize: 1024
      reuseAddress: true
      useServerHeader: false
      useDateHeader: true
      useForwardedHeaders: true

  adminConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 14180
```

I want to change **port** value to **14081** for *applicationConnectors* as there is another **port** exists for *adminConnectors*
After the script execution it should look like:

```
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 14081
      bindHost: 15.213.48.154
      headerCacheSize: 512 bytes
      outputBufferSize: 32KiB
      maxRequestHeaderSize: 8KiB
      maxResponseHeaderSize: 8KiB
      inputBufferSize: 8KiB
      idleTimeout: 30 seconds
      minBufferPoolSize: 64 bytes
      bufferPoolIncrement: 1KiB
      maxBufferPoolSize: 64KiB
      acceptorThreads: 1
      selectorThreads: 2
      acceptQueueSize: 1024
      reuseAddress: true
      useServerHeader: false
      useDateHeader: true
      useForwardedHeaders: true

  adminConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 14180
```

I have tried below code:

```
var1="14081"
var2="port"
sed '/applicationConnectors:/{n;s/\($var2\).*\$/\1${var1}/}' configuration.yml > newfile
mv newfile configuration.yml
```

but it seems this code is not replacing anything.

Comment: Try `sed "/applicationConnectors:/{n;n;s/\($var2\).*/\1: ${var1}/}"`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. It worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed is best for s/old/new, that is all. For anything else just use awk for clarity, portability, robustness, etc. Look:

```
$ awk -v rec='applicationConnectors' -v tag='port' -v val='14081' '
    /^  [^ ]/{name=$1} name==(rec":") && $1==(tag":"){sub(/[^ ]+$/,""); $0=$0 val}
1' file
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 14081
      bindHost: 15.213.48.154
      headerCacheSize: 512 bytes
      outputBufferSize: 32KiB
      maxRequestHeaderSize: 8KiB
      maxResponseHeaderSize: 8KiB
      inputBufferSize: 8KiB
      idleTimeout: 30 seconds
      minBufferPoolSize: 64 bytes
      bufferPoolIncrement: 1KiB
      maxBufferPoolSize: 64KiB
      acceptorThreads: 1
      selectorThreads: 2
      acceptQueueSize: 1024
      reuseAddress: true
      useServerHeader: false
      useDateHeader: true
      useForwardedHeaders: true

  adminConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 14180
```

Want to change `acceptQueueSize:` to `17` instead? It's the same script with just different variable values:

```
$ awk -v rec='applicationConnectors' -v tag='acceptQueueSize' -v val='17' '
    /^  [^ ]/{name=$1} name==(rec":") && $1==(tag":"){sub(/[^ ]+$/,""); $0=$0 val}
1' file
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 14080
      bindHost: 15.213.48.154
      headerCacheSize: 512 bytes
      outputBufferSize: 32KiB
      maxRequestHeaderSize: 8KiB
      maxResponseHeaderSize: 8KiB
      inputBufferSize: 8KiB
      idleTimeout: 30 seconds
      minBufferPoolSize: 64 bytes
      bufferPoolIncrement: 1KiB
      maxBufferPoolSize: 64KiB
      acceptorThreads: 1
      selectorThreads: 2
      acceptQueueSize: 17
      reuseAddress: true
      useServerHeader: false
      useDateHeader: true
      useForwardedHeaders: true

  adminConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 14180
```

Only try that with your currently accepted `sed` solution if you enjoy counting `n`s :-). Note also that this will work no matter what order the lines appear within each record since it keys off the name `port` rather than assuming that will appear some specific number of lines after `applicationConnectors:`. Finally, this will work even if the strings you're searching for or replacing with contain RE metachars (e.g. `.`), backreference chars (e.g. `\1` or `&`), or sed delimiters (e.g. `/`).

Answer (score 0):

Since the port line is the second after `applicationConnectors:` you need to use double `n;` and you should use double quotation marks around the sed command to allow variable interpolation inside:

```
sed "/applicationConnectors:/{n;n;s/\($var2\).*/\1: ${var1}/}" configuration.yml > newfile
```

See this [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/aEU5c1).

Answer (score 0):

```yaml
staging:
  datasource:
    jdbcUrl: xxx
    driverclassname: yyy
    username: zzzz
    password: dddd
    platform: wwww
```

`sed` command to replace value of `jdbc` `url`:

```sh
sed -i "/staging:/{n;n;s/\(jdbcUrl\).*/\1: AAAAA/}" application.yml
```